# How to add an extra tag to the default images tag in Tinymce

Tags: html, web, tinymce, tinymce-5

In **Tinymce** i want to insert the default `<img ... >` **tag** into another extra **tag** to centralized images and add extra class for create zoomable images in my content  .

By default **Tinymce** creates the following html code when add new image :

```
<p> <img ... > </p>
```

What I want and need is something like this :

```
<div class='zoomable content-img'> <img ... > </div>
```

How can I implement this in **Tinymce** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to listen for the `BeforeSetContent` event. Then, if the impending content is an `<img/>` tag, you can replace that with the wrapped version of the HTML markup in the event handler.

Here's a Tiny Fiddle showing a simple (i.e. not very robust, in terms of the img tag check) proof of concept example:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/CQgaab/2

Here's some more information about the BeforeSetContent event:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/events/#beforesetcontent